# Why isn't mediacontroller shown?

Tags: android, mediacontroller

I need to make a `Controller` for my player app. With the help of it user would play, pause, choose next or previous song. But this controller isn't shown and I don't know why?

I have already done method for setting data for controller and class for this controller.

Here's the code of the method:

```
private void setController(){
    controller = new MusicController(this);
    controller.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playNext();
        }
    }, new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playPrev();
        }
    });
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.songList));
    controller.setEnabled(true);
}
```

And here's the code of the class:

```
package asus.example.com.player;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.MediaController;

public class MusicController extends MediaController {
    public MusicController(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void hide(){}
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`show()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html#show()) method needs to be called for it to be shown on screen, when it's not created as part of an `XML Layout`.  At the end of your `setController()` method, call this:

```
controller.show()
```

Comment: So, in such case I have the next problem. When I run the activity I have this: `Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii If you're able to post more of your code, that would be useful, as at the moment I'm not sure how you're calling `setController()`, or from where.